# Apply carousel right slide to a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As you can see I have a table with multiple rows populated from the scope variable users. There is a column in which there is a button(last column). I want this button to behave as a carousel right button. There will be multiple button one for each row. I want all the buttons to behave as a right carousel button. When I click it the current div should slide left and new div must be displayed. With the current code I am able to slide the current div but what I get is one long View Details button(covers the column of all rows) with some faded and other CSS effect which I dont want.
Is there some other way to achieve this.

```html
<tbody> 
  <tr dir-paginate="user in users|orderBy:['state_name','fullname']|filter:{state_name:state_select.name}|itemsPerPage:10" pagination-id="byState"> 
    <td>
      <img src="{{user.party_name}}" style="max-height: 10%;max-width: 10%;" />
    </td> 
    <td>{{user.fullname}}</td> 
    <td>
      <img src="{{user.chamber_type}}" style="max-height: 8%;max-width: 7%;" />{{user.chamber_name}}</td> 
    <td>{{user.district_name}}</td> 
    <td>{{user.state_name}}</td> 
    <td>
      <button type="button" id="{{user.bioguide}}" href="#mySlider" data-slide="next" class="btn btn-primary right carousel-control" value="{{user.bioguide}}" ng-click="getLegislatorDetails($event);">View Details</button>
    </td> 
  </tr> 
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by just removing the carousel-control from the button class.

Changed it to this:-

`<td><button type="button" id="{{user.bioguide}}" href="#mySlider" data-slide="next" class="btn btn-primary right" value="{{user.bioguide}}" ng-click="getLegislatorDetails($event);">View Details</button></td>`

Sorry for posting such a silly thing.